# HELP! My pc wont turn up

Tags: boot

I have an Asus A55V laptop, the os i'm using is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. when i try to turn up my pc sometimes it shows the regular startup display and sometimes it shows like a log in a terminal. But every time it gets stuck, i tried everything i could find on the internet to solve the issue but couldn't. Right now i'm using the live installation to write this post. Is there any chance i can solve the issue without a format.
PS: i have timeshift installed and i have a backup, but i don't know how to solve the issue using it in this situation.

Comment: You can press escape during boot to disable the graphical overlay. What messages is shown when you do this?

Comment: @vidarlo when i did what u told me it gave me the gnu grub display, i think it's called the grub rescue. What can i do now? I'll try to do what waltinator said and i'll give what i've got.

Comment: I ran the journalctrl command, found some lines highlighted in yellow, but i didn't understand what was it about. PS: the date on the journal was Apr 23.

Comment: i tried the boot repair tool, this is the bootinfo summary: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7Bcx5pyKDm/